# SVM Classifier Probability Output is Opposite of RF and CART Classifiers using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, machine-learning

I am working on a Peatland Fire Fire Susceptibility Determination on GEE using three classifier algorithms: RF, CART, and SVM. The outputs are fire probability and binary classification (1 = fire, 0 = no fire) maps. However, I noticed something strange with the probability map from the SVM classifier. The pattern of the probability map is almost the exact opposite of the other two classifiers (picture attached). I have no idea why this happens. I have tried to change the arguments for the SVM classifier to no avail.

Could someone help me figure out what happens with my script?

This is a snippet of the code:

```
// Define SDM function
// Activate the desired classifier, Random Forest or Gradient Boosting.
function SDM(x) {
var Seed = ee.Number(x);
// Randomly split blocks for training and validation
var GRID = ee.FeatureCollection(GridMFinal).randomColumn({seed:Seed}).sort('random');
var trainingGrid = GRID.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));  // Filter points with 'random' property < split percentage
var testingGrid = GRID.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));  // Filter points with 'random' property >= split percentage

// Presence (Incidence)
// var incidencePoints = ee.FeatureCollection(fireIncidence).filter(ee.Filter.eq('PresAbs',1)); //Filter all presence points
var fireInc = ee.FeatureCollection(fireIncidence);
fireInc = fireInc.map(function(feature){return feature.set('Incidence', 1)}); 
var trainFireIncidence = fireInc.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(trainingGrid));  // Filter points with 'random' property < split percentage
var testFireIncidence = fireInc.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(testingGrid));  // Filter points with 'random' property >= split percentage

//Absence (non-incidence)  
var trainPseudoAbs = areaForPA.sample({
                                region: trainingGrid,
                                scale: grainSize,
                                numPixels: trainFireIncidence.size().add(20000),
                                seed: Seed,
                                geometries: true,
                                tileScale: 16
                                });
trainPseudoAbs = trainPseudoAbs.randomColumn().sort('random').limit(ee.Number(trainFireIncidence.size()));  // Filter points with 'random' property < split percentage
trainPseudoAbs = trainPseudoAbs.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('Incidence', 0);
  });  // Filter points with 'random' property >= split percentage

var testPseudoAbs = areaForPA.sample({
                                region: trainingGrid,
                                scale: grainSize,
                                numPixels: trainFireIncidence.size().add(18000),
                                seed: Seed,
                                geometries: true,
                                tileScale: 16
                                });
testPseudoAbs = testPseudoAbs.randomColumn().sort('random').limit(ee.Number(testFireIncidence.size()));  // Filter points with 'random' property < split percentage                                
testPseudoAbs = testPseudoAbs.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('Incidence', 0);
  });  // Filter points with 'random' property >= split percentage

// Merge points
var trainingPartition = trainFireIncidence.merge(trainPseudoAbs);
var testingPartition = testFireIncidence.merge(testPseudoAbs);

// Extract local covariate values from multiband predictor image at training points
var trainPixelValues = predictors.sampleRegions({collection: trainingPartition, properties: ['Incidence'], scale: grainSize, tileScale: 16});

// Classify using random forest
// var Classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
//   numberOfTrees: 500, //The number of decision trees to create.
//   variablesPerSplit: null, //The number of variables per split. If unspecified, uses the square root of the number of variables.
//   minLeafPopulation: 10,//Only create nodes whose training set contains at least this many points. Integer, default: 1
//   bagFraction: 0.5,//The fraction of input to bag per tree. Default: 0.5.
//   maxNodes: null,//The maximum number of leaf nodes in each tree. If unspecified, defaults to no limit.
//   seed: Seed//The randomization seed.
//   });

// Classify using gradient boosting
// var ClassifierPr = ee.Classifier.smileGradientTreeBoost({
//   numberOfTrees:500, //The number of decision trees to create.
//   shrinkage: 0.005, //The shrinkage parameter in (0, 1) controls the learning rate of procedure. Default: 0.005
//   samplingRate: 0.7, //The sampling rate for stochastic tree boosting. Default 0.07
//   maxNodes: null, //The maximum number of leaf nodes in each tree. If unspecified, defaults to no limit.
//   loss: "LeastAbsoluteDeviation", //Loss function for regression. One of: LeastSquares, LeastAbsoluteDeviation, Huber.
//   seed:Seed //The randomization seed.
// });

// Classify using CART //-> the output is the opposite of the other two classifiers
// var Classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart({
//   maxNodes: null, //The maximum number of leaf nodes in each tree. If unspecified, defaults to no limit.
//   minLeafPopulation: 10,//Only create nodes whose training set contains at least this many points. Integer, default: 1
// });

// Classify using SVM
var Classifier = ee.Classifier.libsvm({
  decisionProcedure: 'Margin',
  svmType: 'C_SVC', //One of C_SVC, NU_SVC, ONE_CLASS, EPSILON_SVR or NU_SVR.
  kernelType: 'RBF', //One of LINEAR (u′×v), POLY ((γ×u′×v + coef₀)ᵈᵉᵍʳᵉᵉ), RBF (exp(-γ×|u-v|²)) or SIGMOID (tanh(γ×u′×v + coef₀))
  shrinking: true, //Whether to use shrinking heuristics.
});

// Presence probability 
var ClassifierPr = Classifier.setOutputMode('PROBABILITY').train(trainPixelValues, 'Incidence', bands); 
var ClassifiedImgPr = predictors.select(bands).classify(ClassifierPr);

// Binary presence/absence map
var ClassifierBin = Classifier.setOutputMode('CLASSIFICATION').train(trainPixelValues, 'Incidence', bands); 
var ClassifiedImgBin = predictors.select(bands).classify(ClassifierBin);

return ee.List([ClassifiedImgPr, ClassifiedImgBin, trainingPartition, testingPartition]);}
```

I use this paper as the reference: https://smithsonian.github.io/SDMinGEE/#define-your-area-of-interest-for-modeling

P.S. : I am gonna put some of my asset links in the comment as I'm not allowed to post more than 8 links due to the lack of reps.

[image]

This is my script:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/lukman_fr/buat_TA

Comment: Your assets are not shared: `users/lukman_fr/peat_lands_reproject`, `users/lukman_fr/peatlands_central`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the notice. I updated my link and now it's pointing to my repo instead of just my code editor. Beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, you'll see it defaults to classifying the zero label. Set oneClass = 1 and it should predict correctly.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-libsvm

[image]